# Record types, memorry usage and copy operations

Tags: c#, memory, copy, immutability

If I define a record in C# like

```
public record Pair(int First, int Second);
```

and I have a loop where I do

```
Pair x = new(1, 2);
while (...)
{
    x = new(x.First + 1, x.Second + 1);
}
```

my IDE highlights that line of code after executing my program with a big input size, and tells me that a lot (100MB) are allocated here since the Pair type is immutable and a copy is created (memory allocated) in each loop iteration.

My question is, can I fully trust this statement, or will this be optimized by the compiler?

I have rewritten the code where I make the Pair record a class and provide a method to modify the content so that only one instance is alive during the whole program execution.

```
public class Location
{
    public Location()
    {
        First = 0;
        Second = 0;
    }

    public void Increment() 
    { 
        First++; 
        Second++;
    }

    public int First { get; private set; }
    public int Second { get; private set; }
}
```

So in the loop I can now do:

```
Pair x = new(1, 2);
while (...)
{
    
    x.Increment();
}
```

But when I measure the memory usage with

```
var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
Console.WriteLine($"{proc.PrivateMemorySize64/1000000.0}MB");
```

then the MB used does not really go down, no noticeable difference, which left me wondering.

Comment: *"I have rewritten the code"* ...but you haven't shown it so we can't speak to the differences, and we can't make assumptions as to how you rewrote it or how you're using the rewritten version. If you're still doing the same loop, being mutable or immutable doesn't make a difference because you're still creating a new instance every iteration.

Comment: `public record struct Pair(int First, int Second);` <=== boom

Comment: @madreflection Yes, you are right. I was assuming that it's clear I would be doing that part correctly. Basically, I added custom SetFrom(Pair other) method on the class that would just assign to the Pair, the values of other.

Comment: Don't tell me in a comment. [Edit] the post to include the details. The post should be complete on its own.

Comment: @MarcGravell Omg what happened? Your boom worked!

Comment: It worked because it's a value type (`struct`), which isn't allocated on managed heap like a `record class` is (`record` is a class even if you don't include `class` in the declaration, and that was the only option until `record struct` was introduced). Now that it's a `struct`, though, you have to deal with the implications and any effects that might have (depending on what you're doing with it).

Comment: @madreflection on side-effects: `public readonly record struct Pair(int First, int Second);` - much better ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell: True, but I'm not talking about *side*-effects. I'm talking about direct effects. The decision to use a value type instead of a reference type can have unintended consequences, like the additional overhead required to copy the value to the stack instead of a reference when passing it to a method. This is a trivial case and on a 64-bit architecture, the size of two `int`s and a reference will be the same, but the point is that they work differently and OP needs to keep that in mind. OP's surprise suggests that they have much to learn in that regard.

Comment: Ok, nice I understand. Thank you very much! (I edited the question but it's an oversimplification since I do have a case where I create a new Pair from time to time inside the loop as well and probably that was the reason why I was getting high memory usage ... Hard to simplify.) But already, this key difference that you point out (records are classes and the difference between value type vs. reference type) clarified a lot for me.